# Do Opera plugins have to be written for 64 or 32?

Tags: opera-extension

I'm just looking to see if a plugin for opera has to specifically be tailored or customized for either 32 or 64 bit version of Opera, or are they neutral in that respect?

Answer (score 0):

Extensions are written in JavaScript, which makes them universal (or neutral, as you say).

There is no need to worry about bitness or endianness of the browser (or the operating system).